# What is the difference between tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy and tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

It seems I can't use `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy` instead of `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy`. Why is that?

I have a `trainer` based on [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning):

```
>>>tf.random.set_seed(42)
>>>trainer = CatDogTrainer(initial_epochs=1, model_type='mobile_net')
>>>trainer.metrics
[<tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy at 0x7f2fcc7f72e8>]
>>>trainer.train()
582/582 [==============================] - 55s 94ms/step - loss: 1.8132 - binary_accuracy: 0.7372 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

>>>tf.random.set_seed(42)
>>>trainer = CatDogTrainer(initial_epochs=1, model_type='mobile_net')
>>>trainer.metrics
[<tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.Accuracy at 0x7f0dfd4f8be0>]
>>>trainer.train()
ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

I'm also able to train with `metrics=['accuracy']`. What class does `tf` use in this case? By the way `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy` has an attribute `name` which is `accuracy`.